# spring batch distributed transaction config IBM Liberty

Tags: spring, spring-batch, websphere-liberty

I have to configure spring batch to work in IBM Liberty AS.
The main issue is the configuration of transaction. Some pieces of my configuration.

Inside Liberty server.xml file:

```
<dataSource id="ectxDS"
            jndiName="jdbc/ectxDS"
            isolationLevel="TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE"
            transactional="true">
        <jdbcDriver libraryRef="OracleLib"/>
        <properties.oracle URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:..."
            password="..."
            user="..."/>
    </dataSource>
```

Inside Spring context.xml:

```
<!-- *** DATASOURCE *** -->
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource"
    jndi-name="jdbc/ectxDS"
    expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

<!-- *** JDBC TEMPLATE *** -->
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<!-- *** TX MANAGER *** -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager">
</bean>
```

With this configuration a commit happens where a method of JdbcTemplate class is called (update, query...): I need that Spring Batch manages the transactions according its defaults, for example the method *execute* of a *Tasklet* must be transactional! At the same time I need to use distributed transactions leveraging on class *org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager*.

Perhaps I'm missing something: I have been working with Spring Batch for a very little time.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `the method execute of a Tasklet must be transactional`: The `tasklet` element has an attribute `transaction-manager` used to set the transaction manager to use for that tasklet. By default it is set to a bean named `transactionManager` which in your case should point to `WebSphereUowTransactionManager`. You said `I need to use distributed transactions`: What are the (at least two) distributed resources for which you want to synchronize transactions? Do you have two data sources or a datasource and a queue? Please explain what problem you are trying to solve before your attempted solution.

Comment: Thanks for your response Mahmoud.
At this time, we want Spring Batch to persist job and step metadata in a different database (so we would have 2 databases). And in the future it will be probable that we need to use another one for a total of 3 databases.